# Are these property declarations identical?

Tags: c#, properties

Are these property declarations identical?

```
public int MyProperty { get; private set;}
public int MyProperty { get; }
```

And also these ones?

```
public int MyProperty { get; } = 123;
public int MyProperty => 123;
```

I am asking because I saw mix of these in a source code and they seem to me identical. So I wonder why do they mix coding style in one piece of software, and I need to be sure if I understand it correctly or not. (I mean two separate pairs: line 1 = line 2, and line 3 = line 4.) If not identical, please explain the difference, thanks.

(Note this is not a homework or something. Although it looks like. ;-))

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3847982/713789

Comment: no.  You can change the `{ get; private set;}` from within the class.

Comment: The duplicate doesn't mention the last two pairs, worth noting that the last line is an example of fairly recent syntax introduced in c# 6 ( see expression body properties), and line 3 is the same as line 2, but with a default value provided (the same as if you had set the value of line 2 in the constructor).  Line 4 and Line 3 are the same thing though.

Comment: @MatthewWhited This is not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I didn't intent on closing it out right.  it was just a vote to close.  SO decided I have a high enough score to blanket close.

Comment: All but the first one is covered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047721

Comment: So between the 2 questions its a dupe I guess

Comment: @Servy can you add Jon Skeets link, to the "This question already has an answer here:" as its only a duplicate between the 2? Or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int MyProperty { get; private set;}
public int MyProperty { get; }
```

are not identical

```
public class Myclass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; }

    public void MyFunc()
    {
        MyProperty = 5; //This Is Legal

        MyProperty2 = 6; //This is not
    }
}
```

Similarly for the next pair

```
public class Myclass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; } = 123;
    public int MyProperty2 => 123;

    public Myclass()
    {
        MyProperty = 65; //This is Legal
        MyProperty2 = 104; // This is not
    }
}
```

`MyProperty2` is just a quick syntax for a method that always returns 123. There's no underlying field to it. Hence 123 gets evaluated every time you call it. `MyProperty` is a field which is set to 123 when the Myclass is initialized, and then the get method returns that field. Hence the field can be changed in the constructor.

Comment: Also a big difference between the 2 of the 2nd pair, the value is evaluated once in `public int MyProperty { get; } = 123;` however the value is evaluated every time in `public int MyProperty2 => 123;`, if you had a function call instead of a constant you would see the function get called multiple times.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain. Great point. Added it into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Others have posted that they are not the same, and they are correct.  I'm going to go a little further in to some low level detail though, and show you the IL (Intermediate Language) code generated for each version by the compiler.

### Public getter, private setter vs public getter

The public getter, and private setter:

```
public class Test1
{
    public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

Generates:

```
Test1.get_MyProperty:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery+Test1.<MyProperty>k__BackingField
IL_0006:  ret         

Test1.set_MyProperty:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  stfld       UserQuery+Test1.<MyProperty>k__BackingField
IL_0007:  ret         

Test1..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  ret
```

The version with only the getter:

```
public class Test2
{
    public int MyProperty { get; }
}
```

Generates:

```
Test2.get_MyProperty:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery+Test2.<MyProperty>k__BackingField
IL_0006:  ret         

Test2..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  ret
```

### Public getter vs Expression-Body getter

Getter only:

```
public class Test1
{
    public int MyProperty => 123;
}
```

Generates:

```
Test1.get_MyProperty:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s    7B 
IL_0002:  ret         

Test1..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  ret
```

Expression-Body getter:

```
public class Test2
{
    public int MyProperty { get; } = 123;
}
```

Generates:

```
Test2.get_MyProperty:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery+Test2.<MyProperty>k__BackingField
IL_0006:  ret         

Test2..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s    7B 
IL_0003:  stfld       UserQuery+Test2.<MyProperty>k__BackingField
IL_0008:  ldarg.0     
IL_0009:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_000E:  nop         
IL_000F:  ret
```

As you can see, all 4 of these generate *very* different results behind the scenes at the IL level.

Depending on the compiler optimization settings, these could be different.  The compile *could* choose to remove the backing field if it sees nothing uses it.  It could also do the same for an unused private setter.

It is also possible that they may be jitted (just-int-time compilation) differently as the run-time processes them.